# Разница между способами клонирования

Tags: java, клонирование

Есть ли принципиальная разница между использованием `super.clone()` и созданием нового объекта с помощью `new`?

Пример:

```
public Space clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return (Space)super.clone();
}

public Space clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return new Space(number, square);
}
```

Comment: В `super.clone` точно так же вызовется `new`.

Answer (score 3):

В документации [`Object.clone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) рекомендуется вызывать `super.clone` и приводятся доводы:

> By convention, the returned object should be obtained by calling super.clone. If a class and all of its superclasses (except Object) obey this convention, it will be the case that `x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass()`.
>
> По соглашению, возвращаемый объект должен быть получен путем вызова super.clone. В случае если класс и все его предки (кроме Object) придерживаются соглашения, выполняется равенство `x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass()`.

Дело в том, что `Object.clone` магическим образом возвращает объект, класс которого равен оригинальному. Это важно, т.к. позволяет наследникам не переопределять `clone`.

Приведу пример. Допустим, у класса `Space` есть наследник `Subspace`. Тогда следующий код в нем:

```
Subspace clone = (Subspace) this.clone();
```

,будет работать в первом случае и не будет во втором (вернется класс `Space`), что несколько неожиданно для клона.